# How to signal to gtest that a test wants to skip itself

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a set of **typed** test cases in google test. However, some of these test cases are simply not applicable for a specific type parameter. Consider this example typed test case:

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TheTest, ATest){
    if(TypeParam::isUnsuitedForThisTest()){
        return;
    }
    // ... real test code goes here
}
```

This works well, the test is simply skipped. However, when execution the tests, I see a usual

```
[ RUN      ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest
[       OK ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest (0 ms)
```

so it is not apparent that the test was skipped, it looks like it simply succeeded. I want to somehow display that the test case was skipped. Is there some kind of method in google test to signal that a test case was skipped. Something like this (this does not exist):

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TheTest, ATest){
    if(TypeParam::isUnsuitedForThisTest()){
        SIGNAL_SKIPPED(); // This is what I would like to have
        return;
    }
    // ... real test code goes here
}
```

Then, the output would change to something like this:

```
[ RUN      ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest
[  SKIPPED ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest (0 ms)
```

Is there a feature in gtest that enables such a behaviour?

Comment: Depending how you name your tests, you can use [filters](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests) to run only a subset of your tests.

Comment: @JustinWood: I know. But this is a totally different thing.

Comment: how about putting tests with different type requirements/applicability in a different testcase?

Comment: @AdamKosiorek: This would be okay. However, the information that a test was skipped is *very* important for me, as it quickly tells me which features a specific `TypeParam` does *not* possess. So having a "skip" written in the test result is a lot more meaningful to me than a test that simply does not appear in the test result.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: @gsf: Well, see my answer. That was all I came up with, but it suffices for my use cases.

Comment: I will vote for it, because this is what I do as well, but I actually was hoping for something better. Like being able to skip a test from the SetUp for example.

Comment: For what its worth, there is an open issue for this on gtests github. https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/490. Feel free to voice your 'reaction' there as well and subscribe for the latest status regarding this.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1544

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came up with a simple yet acceptable solution:

Simply print an additional skip line myself using a macro:

```
#define CHECK_FEATURE_OR_SKIP(FEATURE_NAME) \
do{\
  if(!TypeParam::hasFeature(FEATURE_NAME)) {\
     std::cout << "[  SKIPPED ] Feature " << #FEATURE_NAME << "not supported" << std::endl;\
     return;\
  }\
} while(0)
```

Then I can simply use this macro:

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TheTest, ATest){
    CHECK_FEATURE_OR_SKIP(MyFeatureXY);
    // ... real test code goes here
}
```

The result will look as follows:

```
[ RUN      ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest
[  SKIPPED ] Feature MyFeatureXY not supported 
[       OK ] XYZ/TheTest/0.ATest (0 ms)
```

The only small flaw is that there is still an `OK` line, but at least it is apparent that the test case was skipped and also the missing feature is displayed neatly. Another flaw is that a GUI test runner will not display the skip that neatly, but I don't care about this as I only use command line tools to run the test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Since gtest release **1.10.0** the macro `GTEST_SKIP()` is available so you can do something like this:

```
TYPED_TEST_P(TheTest, ATest){
    if(TypeParam::isUnsuitedForThisTest()){
        GTEST_SKIP();  // this ends the test here so no need for return
    }
    // ... real test code goes here
}
```